# How to mock an object, which is instantiated within the tested method

Tags: java, mockito

I want to test a static method MyClass::a in a unit test.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static int a() {
        MyObj myObj = new MyObj();
        return myObj.b();
    }
}
```

How can I mock `myObj.b()` using Mockito and no Powermock?

Comment: Yes. It seems complicated, but it works. Thanks.